# Activar cache en ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Tengo un problema con la cache en una app hecha con Ionic.

Supuestamente activo la caché en el "config" del module de la siguiente manera

```
app.config(function($ionicConfigProvider) {
    $ionicConfigProvider.tabs.position('bottom');
    $ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(5); // <-- aquí
});
```

Aún así, no se activa la caché.

¿Qué puede ser lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta adicionar `cache:true` en el archivo donde administrar tus rutas.

```
$stateProvider.state('estado', {
   url: '/name',
   cache: true,
   controller:'EstadoCtrl',
   templateUrl:'templates/estado.html'
})
```

Comment: Se me olvidó comentarlo, también tengo añadido a cada ruta la cache: true. No sé que más puede ser

Comment: Intenta usar **$ionicConfigProvider.views.forwardCache(true);**

Comment: Se ve que era eso, gracias.